# Select datetime data from SQL Server colum

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, select

```
SELECT [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] 
FROM [BGREX_UpdateQueue]
WHERE [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] <  18/12/2009
```

I want to select those dates from the records where datetime value in column is less than some datetime, we need to compare. I have several value lass than "18/12/2009", but getting no rows returned.

following syntax does not work either

```
SELECT 18/12/2009 // returns 0 
WHERE [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] < '18/12/2009'; // The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

What is the right syntax to pass '18/12/2009' or some other date ? thanks

Comment: If you leave the quotes out, you're asking SQL to calculate 18 / 12 / 2009 (which is 7.4664011946241911398705823792932e-4), cast that to an integer and you get 0. Thanks for the down vote, btw.

Comment: Why don't people reason for down votes ? we can learn about our mistakes if  told

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select next_update_time from bgrex_updatequeue
  where next_update_time < '2009-12-18';
```

Comment: already tried this, gives this error---The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: No, you tried '18/12/2009'.  '2009-12-18' is a different expression entirely, and one that should convert correctly.

Answer (score 2):

try universal SQL Date Format YYYYMMDD

```
WHERE [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] < '20091218'
```

see [standard SQL datetime formats](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2004/05/28/143960.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
SELECT [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] 
FROM [BGREX_UpdateQueue]
WHERE [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] < '2009-12-18'
```

By the way you're getting the `The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.` error because of the date's format, if you try `12/18/2009`, it should work also, but the query above is the best one I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataView, it can be accomplished easily doing this (for example between dates):

```
myDataView = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables["TABLE"], "TIMESTAMP >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) + "' AND TIMESTAMP <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(toDate) + "'", "TIMESTAMP", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

toDate and fromDate are of type `string`

There is also an article on [Working with SQL Server Date/Time Variables: Part Three - Searching for Particular Date Values and Ranges](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm)

Answer (score -1):

[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is your friend in this case.

Comment: I don't mind a down vote, but you might want to let me know what I've gotten wrong. I am always happy to learn more when I am mistaken.

Answer (score -2):

The query in your example is missing quotes around the date, it should be:

```
SELECT [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] 
FROM [BGREX_UpdateQueue]
WHERE [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] <  '18/12/2009'
```

Comment: @asdi: then use a date format that your server expects, 'dd MMM yyyy' always works ('18 Dec 2009')